# Reading a double from a connected thread in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, double

I am currently using the `GraphView` from the developer jjoe64 on GitGub and I was wondering how I would retrieve the `double` I created in my BT connected thread class to the `GraphView` class. This is the original function to call random data, but I want the serial data from my BlueTooth class
The current function in this realtime graph is:

```
private double getRandom() {
    double high = 3;
    double low = 0.5;
    return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}
```

In my Bluetooth class, I have the command `ConnectedThread.read()`, but It's not really working. Here it is:

```
public static double read() {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        double bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
        return bytes;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I it's just my phone that's too slow, it's running Android2.3 (DesireHD), but my professor at my school said it should work fine if I just call `ConnectedThread.read()` and have it equal a `double`. Any advice?

Comment: What does "not really working" mean? Does your thread run correctly? Do you see the data flowing to the thread at all?

Comment: In retrospect, it was just sending the value 1024 and then I was seeing a blank graph the rest of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information for a out-of-the box solution, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

First of all, I presume that `mmInStream` is an `InputStream` or its subclass. Look at the API of `int InputStream.read(byte[] b)`:

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

This means that what you're returning from your `read()` method is just the number of bytes that have been written to the `buffer` from `mmInStream`. That is probably not what you want to do. What you probably want to do is read just the *value* from this stream. To do that you should:

- wrap your `mmInStream` in a `DataInputStream` just after the `mmInStream` is created:

  ```
  mmInStream = yourMethodCreatingInputStream();
  dataInStream = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
  ```
- read the `double` value from the `dataInStream`. But as in all computer systems you must be aware of the exact format that your input value comes in. You must refer to the specification of the device you're using to fetch the input data.

Now the `dataInStream` comes in handy because it abstracts the necessary low-level IO operations and lets you focus on the data. It will automatically translate your queries for the data to the IO operations. For example:

- If your data is in `double` format (and I believe that is the case according to the words of your professor), your `read()` method is as simple as:

  ```
  public static double read() {
      return dataInStream.readDouble();
  }
  ```
- And in case the data is coming in the `float` format:

  ```
  public static double read() {
      return (double)dataInStream.readFloat();
  }
  ```

But again, be sure to consult the specification of the device you're using for the exact format. Some devices may pass you data in exotic formats like for example: "first 2 bytes are the integer part of the resulting value, second 2 bytes are the fractional part". It is up to you as a consumer of the data to follow its format.

Comment: I am pretty sure my arduino Uno is not sending any length bytes, in its serial monitor it is outputting:255.00
254.00
255.00
254.00
255.00
255.00
255.00
255.00
254.00
254.00
It's a double and makes a new value with the serial.println(double) function. Right now my graph app on my android is just recieveing a value of about 1 on the y axis which is where I have the data sent to. I do not know why it's not receiving the actual data being sent from the Arduino, but that is where I am stuck at now. I'm going to double check the code until I might see why.

Comment: And thank you very much for the datainstream knowledge! You have got me through one headache of not knowing I was sending the byte buffersize.

Comment: you're welcome. if you're outputting `double`s using `println` on the arduino, you can parse it on the android device using `Scanner`. simply create it using `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mmInStream)` and parse `double`s using `scanner.nextDouble()` :) good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, that has helped me in a college project on a great magnitude. Do you have a website or blog on the work you have created as an Android programmer? Or a specific app you've created and uploaded to Google Play? I am very grateful for your knowledge in helping my progress

Comment: thank you, I'm glad :) no, I don't have a website nor a blog as I don't have time for it. all the apps I'm creating are private commercial apps used by companies/government so they're not on google play ;)

Comment: Great that sounds like where every programmer wants to be. I was wandering how I can overcome some values that the bluetooth either misses or returns as 0. I have the mhandler on java running at 0 and a delay on my arduino at 30 milisecond. I am guessing I would need to average the value the scanner sends? What are your thoughts? If I put no delay on the arduino it freezes on my android or just comes up as a lot of noise.